# Filter on Date with PowerQuery for first and last day of month

Tags: date, powerquery

In Excel 2019, using PowerQuery, how would you filter dates such that:

1. only the rows with only with the 1st day of the month remain?
2. only the rows with only with the last day of the month remain?

The date is format is: mm/d/yyyy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

For a table with column Date:

1. `Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each Date.Day([Date]) = 1)`
2. `Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each Date.Day([Date]) = EOMONTH([Date]).Day`